# Python problem: Craps game using Monte Carlo estimation in a dice game

Tags: python, montecarlo

Here is the game: the player throws a pair of standard, six-sided dice.

- If the player rolls a total of 7 or 11, the player wins.
- If the player rolls a total of 2, 3, or 12, the player loses.
- For all other roll values, the player will repeatedly roll the pair of dice until either she rolls the initial value again (in which case they win) or 7 (bet is lost.)

Here is my code:

```py
from random import seed, randint

def simulate():
    win_count = 0
    die1 = randint(1, 6)
    die2 = randint(1, 6)
    roll = die1 + die2

    if roll == 7 or roll == 11:
        return True
        win_count += 1
    elif roll == 2 or roll == 3 or roll == 12:
        return False
    else:
        die1 = randint(1, 6)
        die2 = randint(1, 6)
        new_roll = die1 + die2
        while roll != new_roll and roll != 7:
            if new_roll == roll:
                return True
                win_count += 1
            elif new_roll == 7:
                return False

    return win_count

## Main
for trials in range(1000):
    simulate()
print(win_count / 1000)
```

I also need to find the probability of winning the "pass bet", which is what the rules are described above. The number of trials is 1000. However, nothing returns from this code. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In the 7 or 11 case you are returning `True` before `win_count` is incremented. That can't be right. You have this `return win_count` tacked onto the bottom of the function in a place where the flow of computation never (or perhaps seldom) reaches. In any event, in your main function you never even try to do anything with the return value of `simulate`.

Comment: @JohnColeman how would I fix this? I am a beginner .

Comment: @JohnColeman are you saying to have win_count incremented after returning True?